# Movie is played with some delay after calling play on MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, delay, playback

I am developing an iPhone application in which I play the videos using MPMoviePlayerController. Sometimes, some of the videos does not play immediately after I call play on MPMoviePlayerController.

I have called prepareToPlay and in the notified method of MPMediaPlaybackIsPreparedToPlayDidChangeNotification, I am calling play on MPMoviePlayerController.

How can I identify the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the property `movieSourceType` and assign a proper value to it before running `prepareToPlay`.

From [MPMoviePlayerController reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html);

> The default value of this
>   property is MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown.
>   This property provides a clue to the
>   playback system as to how it should
>   download and buffer the movie content.
>   If you know the source type of the
>   movie, setting the value of this
>   property before playback begins can
>   improve the load times for the movie
>   content. If you do not set the source
>   type explicitly before playback, the
>   movie player controller must gather
>   this information, which might delay
>   playback.

Comment: I am trying to play a local file. So, I set MPMovieSourceTypeFile as movieSourceType before calling prepareToPlay. It did not help. Also, I noticed that the problem occurs only in 3GS (4.3)